# ropsten eth что делать

Tags: transactions, ropsten, cpp-ethereum

I sent eth 2.62(NETWORK ETH) ON the eth ropsten wallet address 0xe2fcd50EfdD674C26f894aB5ad71fEcB14b7cDA4(BUT NETWORK ETH (myetherwallet.com)NOT ropsten eth). How to transfer to the wallet Eht 0xAd9BA786b9692371E9DBDcCb8A51ff6ec94C6Fc0 ? TELL MONEY LOST OR CAN BE SEND BACK?

Comment: что делать == what to do???

Comment: If I understand correctly, you sent real Ethers to a Ropsten address? If you have the private key, you can open the same wallet in the mainnet with it.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly . I will look for keys how to make and try. thank you for your knowledge. I will write the answer here for you with respect

Comment: I can just go into the wallet and press the send button, but after 5-10 seconds an error is written